# Xubuntu - How to add a quick launcher to a panel

Tags: xubuntu, software-recommendation, xfce, panel, plugins

I am currently using Xubuntu 14.04. I need something like (and preferably) a panel plugin to open a few programs from it.

More specifically, I want an icon on my panel which opens a box containing launchers to some programs (galculator, sticky notes, xfburn, etc.), and when I click this icon again it disappears. Just like a menu, but **only** with specific launchers.

Is there something like that for Xubuntu? How can I install it?

Comment: As I remember old days, there was something like trays applet. That can hold customized launchers & folder shortcuts. But I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Panel Preferences > Items. Then add a Launcher (top item). Once you add the Launcher click on the gear icon or double click it under Panel Preferences > Items. From there you can add whichever program you like. The option Run Program allows you to add a custom script or item. You can use your own icon for any of the programs, and move it to the top of the list to have your own icon that appears on the Panel. Enjoy!